# converting string to datetime issue c#

Tags: c#, datetime

i have a string like this:

```
1/1/2011
```

i need to convert it to `DateTime`

i have so far tried with no luck:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("1/1/2011"
, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting, and can you post some code so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DateTime.Parse (or better, [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATETIME.TRYPARSE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)) instead of ParseExact.

Comment: Did you use the (string, out DateTime) form?  That should work.  Your format specifier is part of the problem.

Comment: The format specifier is fine for the data given. Using ParseExact is the *right* thing to do when you know the format.

Answer (score 1):

That code should work absolutely fine, and does for me:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("1/1/2011", 
                                          "M/d/yyyy",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}
```

You say you've tried "with no luck" - what happens for you? Can you come up with a similar short but complete program that fails?